# Does かえって処理 mean "altered process"

Tags: grammar, syntax, adverbs

The following text is taken out of a novel.

> 「お人好しもいいですけど、hIE (インターフェース) が動いているところに手を出したら、かえって処理に負荷をかけますよ」

Kengo knew his computers and machines, though. “Best not interfere when an
Interfacer is at work. You'll only get in the way.” By Interfacer he meant hIE of course, a Humanoid Interface Element, an android in human form.

My attempt:

> It's nice of you, but if you interfere when an Interfacer is working, it will rather put a heavy load on the process.

or

> It's good-hearted of you and all but, if you interfere when an Interfacer is working, the altered process will cause an overload.

Not sure if it's 変って処理 or 却って処理.

Comment: 変える is ichidan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60803/%e3%81%8b%e3%81%88%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e7%96%8e%e3%81%be%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%ae%e6%84%8f%e5%91%b3%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6 ?

Comment: And of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57852/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%82%80%e3%81%97%e3%82%8d-and-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%88%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6 ?

Comment: All of you people who have replied have been great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure if its 変って処理 or 却って処理

The former would read [変]{かわ}って. You might have been thinking of [変]{か}える.

By elimination it is thus the latter, meaning "on the contrary" to emphasize that the good intention is misguided (and it is not related to 処理).

As for 負担をかける, I would agree with "overload" if talking about an automated process, but if the object is sentient (an android is reasonably close to a person), then the idea is more *being a burden* to them, so "get in the way" would be my choice.